# Teamviewer - How to unlock a locked computer

Tags: windows-7, teamviewer

This is my first time attempting to connect to a remote and locked computer, from my local computer via Team Viewer.

I have been going through all the options, extras, etc and I have allowed Full Access to Team Viewer on the remote, locked computer. I have also set a personal password for 'Unattended Access'.

Please note: I have not had the opportunity to test whether or not this will work yet. I would like to know if:

1. This is possible.
2. If it is possible, what steps do I need to do in order to ensure I can do so.
3. By allowing Full Access and setting up a password for 'Unattended Access' have I done all I need to do?

Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Is Teamviewer running when the machine is locked? I think you might need to install the headless version for this to work correctly.

Comment: @Burgi it is, I will look into the headless version and verify that I don't already have it.

Comment: It is actually called [host](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/custom-modules/index.aspx?module=Host&os=Windows). This [page](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/use-cases/remote-access/) has more info.

Comment: I will try this overnight and update you tomorrow, thanks for the tips so far

Comment: From my experience - As long as you don't shutdown Teamviewer - and simply "Lock" the computer - it will stay running. Note: If the computer goes to sleep / hibernate - it won't work.